# launching screen clears x11 clipboard

Tags: x11, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, clipboard

Every time I launch screen(1), it clears my X11 clipboard. This is incredibly frustrating. I assume there's some default setting I can disable? I haven't been able to find it yet.

Using gnome terminal on Fedora 22.

Comment: It doesn't do it for me (F22 + Gnome), and `screen` doesn't talk to X.  Perhaps you have a shell alias which does this.

Comment: I have this problem as well. I have to paste into a text editor, open or reattach screen, then copy from the text editor. I'm on Linux Mint 18, which also uses Gnome Terminal.

Comment: It does this for me (F24 + Gnome), and it is decidedly not a shell alias. Clearing the middle-click buffer is traditional, if annoying, behavior. This, though, is new.

Comment: I've also noticed that the clipboard is cleared even when running screen on a remote server. This behaviour would likely be dependent on X11-Forwarding.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a [bug in VTE](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789954), a compoment used by GNOME Terminal. `screen` resets the terminal when it is started, and due to the bug, the clipboard content is lost.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a workaround - not a "proper" answer.*

Personally I think this is a bug in the behaviour - and I suspect it is related to the fact that screen has its own copy/paste clipboard feature. But I'm not at all certain. :-/

My workaround is to install a clipboard manager. I won't make any specific recommendations. A quick Google revealed the following examples:

- CopyQ - Qt-based
- Diodon - intended for Unity/GTK
- Glipper - GTK-based
- Parcellite - GTK-based
- xfce4-clipman - for xfce (I use XFCE, so am using this one myself)